# How can I add core GNU commands to a pre-existing AIX system?

Tags: ksh, aix, gnu

In another thread ([What's the easiest way to sort a list like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409311/whats-the-easiest-way-to-sort-a-list-like-this)) someone asked if we had "GNU ls" on the system because it would provide a solution.  We do NOT have GNU ls installed but it got me thinking:

1. when you install things like "GNU ls" does it just install "ls" or does
      it contain replacements for a suite of Unix commands?
2. Would GNU ls support all the flags that the base-O/S ls command supports?

The second question is because we have a lot of ksh93 scripts on our AIX systems, and I want to ensure they continue to function as expected.  If I installed GNU ls, would I just use a fully-qualified path to GNU ls when I needed it's functionality in a given ksh script, say /opt/GNU/ls?  Is that how one would typically add/use a GNU command on a mature system?

Comment: Taken from https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013993693 : Download and install the GNU Coreutils from AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/p/os/aix/linux/download.html

This is going to install many commands under the /usr/linux/bin path

Comment: Many of the packages in the [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/) install to a separate tree, such as /opt/freeware, and create symlinks to /usr/bin or /bin. I don't see an `ls` package there. If you compile from source, then you'd be free to place it anywhere you like.

Comment: Some package or ports systems prefix the GNU commands with `g` so you would run `gls` which would help avoid confusion with the base OS version of the program, assuming a `PATH` set to contain sets of utilities.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, has `ksh93` been built with the `ls` builtin on AIX (`command /opt/ast/bin/ls --man`)? It is at least as feature full as GNU `ls`.

Comment: @ Stéphane: `command /opt/ast/bin/ls --man` results in: `ksh93: /opt/ast/bin/ls: not found`.  With a `$SHELL` of /usr/bin/ksh93, `type ls` results in: `ls is /usr/bin/ls`

Comment: Scavenger, in order to make this answerable, I think we'd need to pin down *how* you'd install GNU ls, and not leave it open-ended as in `things like GNU ls`, and also where you'd install it *from*.

Comment: I'm not a Unix admin, so this isn't something I'd do.  I happen to have a meeting with our admin this afternoon.  I'll ask how he'd usually install freeware so it has no impact on existing software.  Looking at one system I see we have gnu tar in /opt/freeware/tar/ but "type tar" points to file /bin/tar.  So, our admin has installed other gnu tools before.  I just want to ensure that any gnu tools he installs for my use remain as one-off tools I'd have to reference explicitly.

Comment: Or, if the sysadmin is averse to installing more packages, continue tagging your questions with [tag:AIX] and make it clear which GNU tools you can/can not rely on.

Comment: He's not averse to installing packages so I'll get him to install the GNU CoreUtils.   As someone mentioned above, the "GNU Coreutils from AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications" doesn't appear to have ls included, so GNU CoreUtils see like the way to go.  Thanks everyone. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can build [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) from source, and manually copy the resulted ls(1) command as another name, under PATH, such as `/usr/bin/gls`.

For example the simplest steps are:

```
./configure <configure-options-you-may-want>
make
cp src/ls /usr/bin/gls
```

Answer (score 0):

1. That depends on how you install your GNU binaries. The most common way is either [Michael Perzls site](https://www.perzl.org) or [IBMs AIX Toolbox for Open Source Software](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/aix-toolbox-open-source-software-downloads-alpha). In either case (and most probably with other packages too, although i have never used any other than these two) binaries are not getting installed in /bin and so do not overwrite the systems binaries. In this case you can select which binaries - AIX or GNU - to use simply by changing your PATH variable. i.e.:

```
      PATH=/usr/local/gnu/bin             # GNU binaries
      PATH="$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin"          # AIX system binaries
      PATH="$PATH:/some/other/path:[...]"
      export PATH
```

Reverse the first two lines (GNU binaries are supposedly installed in `/usr/local/bin` here) to revert to using the AIX binaries (first).

Similar for the content of the package: that depends on which package you use, although AFAIK there is no package containing GNU-ls from IBM.

2. This is hard to say. GNU tools are quite volatile and follow now given ruleset (like, i.e. AIX does with POSIX), so what is correct today might well be wrong tomorrow or vice versa. Some GNU utilities try to follow POSIX rules, others don't. I suppose even this attitude changes over time as the population of contributors to a certain utility changes.