# Writing a ksh-script with a predefined time-out

Tags: shell-script, ksh, aix, background-process

My OS is AIX (7.2) and my shell is ksh88 (preferably) or ksh93, if necessary.

I want to write a script that sets some maximum timer for its execution. If it manages to finish its task within this time constraint it shoud exit normally but if this timer goes off it should stop immediately, regardless of the task being finished or not.

My naive implementation looks like this:

```
#! /bin/ksh

function pTimer
{
typeset -i iProcID=$1                            # process ID of main process

sleep $CiMaxTime

print -u2 - "TIMER: time is up, aborting $0"     # terminate if time is up
kill -15 $iProc

exit 1
}


# main()
typeset -i iProc=$$
typeset -i CiMaxTime=60                          # maximum time in seconds

pTimer $iProc &

# ... actual work done here.
exit 0
```

This *more or less works* but alas, there are regularly processes left over after the script exits regardless of the script being terminated by the timer or exiting "regularly". Somehow my understanding of the shells process management seems to be off. What do I have to do so that all "remains" are cleanly removed once the script exits?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the timeout command

```
timeout DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
```

where `DURTATION` is your timeout duration and `COMMAND` and `ARG` are your script and its arguments.

For example

```
/usr/bin/time timeout 5 sleep 10
```

shows

```
0.00user 0.00system 0:05.01elapsed
```

Which means that the "sleep 10" was actually terminated in 5 second.

Comment: AIX does not have a native `timeout` command, as far as I know, so you should probably also mention how to get access to this command on AIX 7.2.

Comment: For installing coreutils on aix - check this thread https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688708/116259